# Why don't I see the reputation gain?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Today I answered https://mathoverflow.net/a/178155 for the first time a question, and afterwards received an email to complete my registration.

But upon completion I now only see the 101 points from registering, not the points from 4 upvotes on my answer.

What happened?

Comment: Hi Arnold, just [drop us a line](http://mathoverflow.net/contact) and we'll get your unregistered accounts moved over. Primarily, it's only important that you include the links, as they are unregistered there's a good chance you can't do anything else that the system asks. Password reset won't work, because they were disenfranchised pre-se2.0.

Comment: @TimPost: I followed the procedure indicated in the answer below, but I still have two accounts. Somehow the system must know, as it uses my photograph for both, although I registered only once. So I think there is a bug in the program for registering.

Answer (score 7):

It's not your user.

Note that https://mathoverflow.net/users/56920/arnold-neumaier is a registered user who have no posts.

Whereas https://mathoverflow.net/users/56919/arnold-neumaier is an unregistered user which has a single post with four upvotes, and 41 points of reputation.

If you still have access to the unregistered account (through some browser window somewhere), you can register it using the same credentials you registered this account. The system will merge them and you'll have the points. If you don't, you can look here: https://mathoverflow.net/contact and use the option about merging accounts.

Comment: It didn't work; see my comment to the question.

Comment: Did you send the community team an email, as Tim Post suggested?

Comment: The suggestion in the link ''drop us a line'' lead to the contact page with a menu, where I first tried ''merge accounts'' then ''other''. Neither worked. I don't have the email address of the community team.

Comment: Perhaps you should try once more?

Comment: now it is merged. Thanks!